# pattern template/*.tmpl: no matching files found

Tags: go, embed

I can't build the project
web/render.go:11:36: pattern template/*.tmpl: no matching files found
Even though I have .tmpl files

```
.
├── cmd
│  └── twit
│ └── main.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── Web
     ├── handler.go
     ├── login.go
     ├── render.go
     └── template
         ├── include
         │ └── layout.tmpl
         └── login.tmpl
```

embed is also available

```
var templateFS embed.FS

func parseTmpl(name string) *template.Template {
   tmpl := template.New(name)
   tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseFS(templateFS, "template/include/*.tmpl"))
   return template.Must(tmpl.ParseFS(templateFS, "template/"+name))
}
```

Comment: Where in your code is the [embed directive](https://pkg.go.dev/embed@go1.20.4#hdr-Directives)?

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you have the pattern `template/*.tmpl`. So that error is not from the code in your question. Your code is also incomplete since it does not include any `import` or `//go:embed` statements. In other words: You provided insufficient information for us to be able to help you.